# How to use the getIdToken() auth method in firebase version 9?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

How to use the `getIdToken()` auth method in firebase version 9?

It works like this below in version 8

```
import firebase from "firebase";

const token = await firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(/* forceRefresh */ false);
```

I tried this in version 9 but it is not working

```
import { getIdToken } from "firebase/auth";

const token = await getIdToken(/* forceRefresh */ false);
```

I also tried this below and it is not working

```
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();
const { currentUser } = auth;

const token = await currentUser.getIdToken(/* forceRefresh */ false);
```

Comment: `getIdToken` is still a method on the `User` object in v9 as shown here https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.user.md#usergetidtoken. What isn't working about the last code snippet in your question? Did you step through it in a debugger yet? Does `currentUser` have a value? Does `currentUser.uid` have a value?

Comment: Yes ```currentUser``` does have a vaule, how would suggest I use the ```getIdToken ``` method in v9? @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: Same as before, so what happens when you run that last line in the last snippet?

Comment: Got this error ```[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'currentUser.getIdToken')]``` @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: That sounds like `currentUser` is `null`. If you do `if (currentUser === null) throw "No current user"` right before calling ID token, that should be easy to test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getIdToken()` function takes `User` as parameter and not the `refreshToken` boolean as in name-spaced SDK.

```
import { getIdToken, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";

onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (user) => {
  if (user) {
    const token = await getIdToken(user);
  }
});
```

As far as the error goes, `getAuth()` returns auth instance but user's auth state might now have loaded yet. Try running the same in `onAuthStateChanged` or adding a null check as suggested by @Frank.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like `getIdToken()` function takes two arguments in the latest version (9.6.6): user and a boolean. So, this is the working code in my case:

```
import { getAuth, getIdToken } from "firebase/auth"

const auth = getAuth()
const { currentUser } = auth
const token = await getIdToken(currentUser, true)
```

Comment: The `true` forces the token to be refreshed every time you call it.